# detecting before/after pages in \backrefentrycount

Tags: hyperref, back-referencing

I'm using memoir, (optionally) hyperref, and backref. In the back references of my bibliography, I want all the references that come before the Endnotes "chapter" to be formatted differently. The hooks seem to be there. I can insert a label or anything else to identify where the Endnotes "chapter" begins. After some study and experimenting, I've proven only that I don't know LaTeX well enough to attempt this. Conceptually, I think I want something like this:

```
\renewcommand*{\backrefentrycount}[2]{%
\ifnum \getrefnumber{#1}>\getrefnumber{chap:Endnotes} %
#1%
\else %
\textbf{#1}%
\fi%
}%
%
```

But of course, something that actually works, instead of this. I (think) I really just want to end up comparing two raw page offsets without regard for any other kind of numbering issues (like preface roman numeral page numbers), but I can't figure out if there's any such mechanism available or if the job is more difficult than I imagine.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that visualizes what you're after, rather than providing small snippets of code?

Comment: Probably what I was after was avoiding learning my 19th macro language, but such is life. After learning how to turn on macro tracing, I found that \backrefcount gets passed a first argument that looks like "\backrefxxx {109}{1.21}{chapter*.235}". Given that, I inserted a "\def\rlbpick##1##2##3##4{##2}" and then the conditional became "\ifnum \rlbpick#1>100". Fragile, breaks if given non-numeric page, and probably ugly, but it gets me going for now. I'll see if I can clean it up as I learn more.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>The OP answered his question in comment so I switch it to an answer.</sub>

`\backrefcount` gets passed a first argument that looks like `\backrefxxx {109}{1.21}{chapter*.235}`. Given that, I inserted a `\def\rlbpick##1##2##3##4{##2}` and then the conditional became `\ifnum \rlbpick#1>100`.

Fragile, breaks if given non-numeric page, and probably ugly, but it gets me going for now. I'll see if I can clean it up as I learn more.